# C# Clone Class with recursive Collections

Tags: c#, clone, observablecollection

i have a Class bound to a wpf treeview like this

```
public class Vorlageneintrag : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string erw_Ausgabe { get; set; }
        public string erw_Pfad { get; set; }
        public string erw_Mailadresse { get; set; }
        ...
        public ObservableCollection<Vorlageneintrag> Items {get; set;}
        ...
 public Vorlageneintrag Copy()
        {
            return (Vorlageneintrag)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
```

works fine, now i added a Filterfunction, that removes all not filter matching "Vorlageneintrag". Works as i want. But now my Problem:
How can get i the original List back to reset my Filter?
reseting Itemssource by using .toList() or .MemberwiseClone() from a copy works only for the first "Layer" but not for Vorlageneintrag.Items or Vorlageneintrag.Items[0].Items and deeper (there can be "unlimited" Sub-sub-sub...-trees). Or will it better to create/fill a complete new object?

Edit:
Filtering:

```
 List<Vorlageneintrag> temp =((ObservableCollection<Vorlageneintrag>)tree_vorlagen.ItemsSource).ToList();
              
                ObservableCollection<Vorlageneintrag> orglist=((ObservableCollection<Vorlageneintrag>)tree_vorlagen.ItemsSource);

             
                    foreach (var item in temp)
                    {
                    
                  
                    if(Loopandfilter(item).Items.Count==0)
                    {
                       orglist.Remove(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.IsNodeExpanded = true;
                    }


                    }

 private Vorlageneintrag Loopandfilter(Vorlageneintrag item)
        {
            if(item.Items.Count==0)
            {
                item.IsNodeExpanded = true;
                return item;
            }
            else
            {

                List<Vorlageneintrag> temp = item.Items.ToList();
               
                foreach (Vorlageneintrag tmp_item in temp)
                {

                 
                    
                    if (Loopandfilter(tmp_item).Items.Count == 0)
                    {
                        if (!tmp_item.erw_Ausgabe.ToLower().Contains(tb_qicksearch.Text.ToLower()))
                        {
                            item.Items.Remove(tmp_item);
                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            
                            item.IsNodeExpanded = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
              
            return item;
        }
```

Comment: By "Filterfunction", do you mean [CollectionViewSource.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter)?

Comment: Can you show how you are doing the filtering?

Comment: @KlausGütter no i remove them from the ObservableCollection

Comment: @Xerillio added Filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `MemberwiseClone()` you are creating a **shallow** copy, meaning that the `Items` collection items will not be copied, but rather the reference to the collection itself will be copied, so both the original and the cloned `Vorlageneintrag` objects will refer to the same `Items` collection. To make a deep copy that will be independent of the original object you can do this:

```
public class Vorlageneintrag : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string erw_Ausgabe { get; set; }
    public string erw_Pfad { get; set; }
    public string erw_Mailadresse { get; set; }
    
    public ObservableCollection<Vorlageneintrag> Items { get; set; }
    
    public Vorlageneintrag Copy()
    {
        var shallowClone = (Vorlageneintrag)MemberwiseClone();
        if (shallowClone.Items == null)
            return shallowClone;

        var cloneItems = new ObservableCollection<Vorlageneintrag>();
        foreach (var item in Items)
            cloneItems.Add(item.Copy());

        shallowClone.Items = cloneItems;
        return shallowClone;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Also since you are likely have a binding to `Items` you probably should invoke `PropertyChanged` event in the `Items` setter, although that depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you, works great =) (It was not the full class in my example, only a little part)